# Python tkinter: Continuously updating labels in frame

Tags: python, tkinter

In my code I have a spin box that the user uses to select the number of teams they want, then in a separate frame columns are created to match the number of teams they chose, and when they use the spin box to change this value it also changes the number of columns

```
frame=Frame(root)
frame.pack(anchor=CENTER)
Label(frame,text='Team selection').grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=5)

NumTeams=StringVar()
Spinbox(frame,values=(1,2,3,4,5),textvariable=NumTeams).grid(row=2,column=0,columnspan=5)

frame2=Frame(root)
frame2.pack()
for i in range(int(NumTeams.get())):
    Label(frame2,text=str(i)).grid(row=0,column=i)
    frame2.update()
```

The above code is an attempt at achieving this, does anyone know a way that this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `command` argument to specify a method to be run whenever your spinbox changes values. I'm not entirely sure what type of columns you mean, but hopefully you can work with this.

```
from Tkinter import *

def on_spin():
    num_teams.set("New text")

root = Tk()

frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack(anchor=CENTER)

frame2 = Frame(root)
frame2.pack()

num_teams = StringVar()
label = Label(frame2, textvariable=num_teams)
label.pack()

spin = Spinbox(frame, from_=1, to=5, command=on_spin)
spin.pack()

root.mainloop()
```